# How do you send an email using PHP and also include a CC?

Tags: php, email, header, cc

This question has been asked many times. I have looked at the other ones. I think my problem is different.

The code works without the CC header. However when I put the CC header my Mac Mail application acknowledges the CC and it says "Downloading 2 mails" aka the mail that was sent in the $to and the new mail in the Cc... but the email in the CC never comes.

```
    <?php
       $to = "myEmail@gmail.com";
       $subject = "Test Email";
       $body = "Hi, This is a Test Email";
       $headers = "From: Test@MyWebsite.com \r\n";
       $headers .= 'Cc: myOtherEmail@gmail.com' . "\r\n";


       if ( mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
          echo("Email successfully sent to $to");
       } else {
          echo("Email sending failed...");
       }
    ?>
```

Comment: Does the CC email show up if you look directly in Gmail? This sounds like a client issue, not a PHP one.

Comment: Have you tried with one address as **to** and another one (different address) as your **cc**?  ThatNewbieDude :)

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes. It does. I'm stumped.

Comment: @statosdotcom Yes. I tried that already lol. It doesn't work, can you try?

Comment: Solved it I guess..... not really happy with the solution... but ok for now. Posted the answer.

Comment: Don't bother with `mail()`.  It's not meant for anything complicated... and e-mail is complicated!  Check out PHPMailer and other libraries.

Comment: Gmail and Google sux

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys...  I solved it... hopefully this helps somebody......

It only seems to work gmail to gmail. I don't know why. Hopefully someone with more experience can say why. But I tried @yahoo, @hotmail, @myWebsite emails in the $to and $from.

Comment: If your second account is set up in Gmail as an alias of the *first* account, Gmail (intelligently) considers them to be one email rather than doubling up on them.

Comment: ^^^That's the answer.

Comment: My friend, if possible, accept your own answer. This is best practice here in S.O. and too alerts users that the question is already been answered. Thanks.